# How to remove errors from consul in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, logging, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I have a question regarding the consul output.
I have this code in my program:

```
   public static void ClickElementWhenClickable(By locator ) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_WAITE, SECONDS);
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        while (Instant.now().isBefore(now.plusSeconds(IMPLICIT_WAITE)))
        {
            try
            {
                new WebDriverWait(driver, IMPLICIT_WAITE).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();

                return;
            }
            catch (WebDriverException e)
            {
                // do nothing, loop again
            }

        }

        throw new Exception("Not able to click element <" + locator + "> within " + IMPLICIT_WAITE + "s.");
    }
```

It is working fine. and click element only when it is clickable, and wait some seconds.
The problem occurred in cases the element is not found for some times, and selenium print the errors to the consul.

Example:

```
Fri Nov 01 14:59:55 IST 2019:ERROR: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-mig-c11="" class="avatar-style ant-btn ant-btn-default ant-btn-circle" id="header-account" nz-button="" nz-popover="" nzplacement="bottomRight" nzshape="circle" nztrigger="click" ng-reflect-nz-shape="circle" ng-reflect-nz-content="[object Object]" ng-reflect-nz-trigger="click" ng-reflect-nz-placement="bottomRight" ng-reflect-directive-name-title="" nz-wave="[object Object]">...</button> is not clickable at point (1888, 31). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion"
```

[image]

Is there a way not to show this errors(Only if I am in this method)?
I want to mentioned that the test is past, selenium waits for the element to be clickable and than click on it. However in all the waiting time it just print this errors that I do not need.
I want it to print the error only in case the time is up, and the element is not clickable.

for example if the time is: 13:15:00 and the IMPLICIT_WAIT is 12 seconds.
Only at 13:15:13  I will receive an error, and not between (Meanning I am in the while loop)

Currently tests are passed and the consul full with errors of wasting.
I just want that if I  use this specific method the errors will not be printed.
regards

Comment: This will probably be a setting in your IDE, and not in Selenium. This isn't exactly a Selenium question -- what IDE are you using, and what language?

Comment: Intelij  I just want it not to be displayed in this method. Like to catch errors like catching exceptions

Comment: From my experience, exceptions are always printed in the console, whether it is a caught or un-caught exception. The only way I know to not display an exception message is by modifying your IDE and / or build settings.